# commandLink submitForm error after JDeveloper 11.1.1.6 install

Tags: jsf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I installed JDeveloper 11.1.1.6 and opened a simple test project that was originally created in 11.1.1.5. Now, when clicking on a JSF commandLink (h:commandLink), I receive the following error in the web browser console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined

My web.xml contains the following entries:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  ...
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Integrated Weblogic is at version 10.3.5.

There is no outside or custom JavaScript being referenced within this application.

Has anyone experienced this behavior and found a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution provided on the JDeveloper Forum on OTN: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10389015

In short: use af:commandLink

Frank

Comment: Thank you for posting my thread here. I had forgotten to do so.